# Conditional formatting for geom_line() depending on the direction and significance of the trend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to build a plot using ggplot2 that communicates a few ideas jointly in a conditional manner:

1. Compared to a set goal (90%), ~x% of individuals found a course to be helpful indicating that we are either (i) underperforming relative to this goal, (ii) meeting this goal, or (iii) overperforming relative to this goal. NOTE: Ideally each of these factor levels has a color, such as red, yellow, and green (which I've achieved in a conditional manner).
2. Compared to prior averages (~y%), the trend in recent history is either (a) positive (indicating that we've seen some improvements), (b) negative (indicating that we've gotten worse over time), or (c) has made no significant changes. NOTE: Ideally each of these factor levels has a color as well mirroring the prior color scheme.

Unfortunately, I  cannot conceive of a way to do #2 in a conditional manner; hence why I need help. Ideally, when the trend is positive and  significant (i.e., confidence intervals from separate periods do not overlap), the geom_line() is green; when the trend is neutral/non-significant (i.e., the confidence intervals from the separate periods  do overlap), the geom_line() is grey; when the trend is negative and  significant (i.e., confidence intervals from separate periods do not overlap), the geom_line() is red [note: the example below is an illustration of this negative and significant trend].

What I've tried thus far is below.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(binom)
```

```
# Build dataset
item <- c("Proficiency in designing spreadsheets.","Proficiency in designing spreadsheets.")
year <- c("Spring 2014 (n = 129)", "Fall 2018 (n = 47)")
year2 <- c("2014","2018")
term <- c("Spring", "Fall")
n.helpful <- as.numeric(c(124, 35))
n <- as.numeric(c(129, 47))
goal <- as.numeric(c(.90,.90))
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(item,year2, term, year,n.helpful,n,goal))
df$n <- as.numeric(as.character(df$n))
df$goal <- as.numeric(as.character(df$goal))
df$n.helpful <- as.numeric(as.character((df$n.helpful)))

# Add confidence interval
CI <- binom.confint(x = df$n.helpful, n = df$n , conf.level = .90, methods = "exact")
CI <- round(CI[c(4:6)],3)

# Bind CIs to df
df <- cbind(df,CI)

# Add statistically significant (alpha = .10) terms.
df$goal.dev <- ifelse(df$goal > df$upper, "Underperforming", ifelse(df$goal <= df$upper & df$goal >= df$lower, "Meeting", ifelse(df$goal < df$lower, "Exceeding",0)))
```

```
#Colour Palette
pal <- c(
  "Underperforming" = "#FF9999",
  "Meeting" = "#FFFF99", 
  "Exceeding" = "lightgreen" 
)

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = mean, group =  1, fill = goal.dev)) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = year, y = mean), stat = "identity", width = .6)+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1), limits = c(0,1)) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c(limits = rev(levels(df$goal.dev)))) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = pal,
    limits = names(pal)
  ) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Spring 2014 (n = 129)", "Fall 2018 (n = 47)")) +
  geom_line(colour="#CC0003", size = 1) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=lower, ymax=upper), width=.1) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("red")) +
  geom_text(aes(x = year, y = mean, label = sprintf("%0.1f%%",mean*100,"%")), size=4, vjust = 8) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=.90, linetype="dashed", color = "red") +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("% Moderately Helpful to Very Helpful") +
  ggtitle("Proficiency in designing spreadsheets.")
```

While I'm getting the results I want, I'd like to do #2 in a conditional manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solutions is using `geom_segment` instead of `geom_line()`, which can be coloured individually for each segment.
First you would need some code to check that this trend is negative and put this in a `data.frame`.

```
line_df <- lapply(seq_along(nrow(df) - 1), function(i){
  trend = "stable"
  trend = if(df[i, "lower"] > df[i + 1, "upper"]) {
    "decreasing"
  } else if (df[i, "upper"] < df[i + 1, "lower"]) {
    "increasing"
  }
  out <- data.frame(x = df[i,"year"],
                    xend = df[i + 1, "year"],
                    y = df[i, "mean"],
                    yend = df[i + 1, "mean"],
                    trend = trend)
})
line_df <- do.call(rbind, line_df)
line_df$trend <- factor(line_df$trend,
                        levels = c("decreasing", "stable", "increasing"))
```

Wherein `line_df$trend` is a factor that we'll use for the colour.
Then would come the ggplot code:

```
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = year, y = mean, group =  1, fill = goal.dev)) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = year, y = mean), stat = "identity", width = .6)+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1), limits = c(0,1)) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Spring 2014 (n = 129)", "Fall 2018 (n = 47)")) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = pal,
    limits = names(pal)
  ) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=lower, ymax=upper), width=.1) +
  geom_text(aes(x = year, y = mean, label = sprintf("%0.1f%%",mean*100,"%")), size=4, vjust = 8) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=.90, linetype="dashed", color = "red") +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("% Moderately Helpful to Very Helpful") +
  ggtitle("Proficiency in designing spreadsheets.") +
  geom_segment(data = line_df,
               aes(x = x, xend = xend, y = y, yend = yend, colour = trend),
               inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  scale_color_manual(values = setNames(c("red", "yellow","green"), 
                                       levels(line_df$trend)),
                     breaks = levels(line_df$trend)),
                     labels = levels(line_df$trend))
```

Especially the last two functions are doing the majority of the conditional formatting. The `geom_segments()` tells it to draw segments at start and end x and y positions. I've set `inherit.aes()` to false because otherwise I had to rename x and y in the `line_df` data.frame. This allows us to set the colours per segment, instead of per line as in `geom_line()`.

Then, the `scale_colour_manual` is actually attaching the conditional formatting to colour aesthetics.

Hope this was helpful!

Comment: There was a slight formatting issue that appeared for me on the "breaks = levels()" line...specifically an extra/unnecessary parenthesis. After deleting it, everything appeared to work! Once I have more data analyzed, I'll let you know if I run into any troubles. Thanks again!